# How to make a bash script to take input from command line (positionals), stdout (pipe), and process substitution?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, scripting

I wrote a script that takes a bunch of options (`-d`, `-v`, `-l`, as well as `--version`, `--leader`, etc...) and then the rest of the text (`$*`) can be anything. The script processes the text and spits it out reformatted. It's quite long, so here's a condensed version:

```sh
## –––––––––––––––––––––––––[ myScript.sh ]–––––––––––––––––––––––––– ##

# (1) Set up default values

declare -- v='1.0' FS=$':\n\r\v\f\t'  Application='Finder' Files s='s'
declare -i errors=0 element=0 counter=0 n L=2

# (2) Parse user input
until [[ -z "$1" || "$1" == '--' || "${1:0:1}" != '-' ]]; do
    [ "$Input" ] && unset Input
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^(-[Ww]|--[Ww]idth=)([0-9]+)? ]]; then
        Input=$(echo "$1" | gsed -re 's|--?W(idth=)?||I' | grep -Eoe '^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')
        [ -z "$Input" ] && echo "$2" | grep -Eoe '^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$' && Input="$2" && shift 1
        (( Input >= 0 )) && Width="$Input" || unset Width
    elif [[ "$1" =~ ^((-[LlIi]|--(([Ll]ead(er|ing)?)?([Ii]n(dent)?)|[Ll]ead(er|ing)?)=)([0-9]+)?)$ ]]; then
        Input=$(echo "$1" | gsed -re 's|--?[a-z]+=?||I' | grep -Eoe '^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')
        [ -z "$Input" ] && echo "$2" | grep -Eoe '^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$' && Input="$2" && shift 1
        (( Input >= 0 )) && L="$Input" || unset L
    ...
    else printf "$(Bold 'Error:') Unrecognized option: '$(Tbrown "$1")'\n\n" >&2
        exit 2
    fi
    shift 1
done

#(3) Now here, get text
IFS=''
[ -n "${*}" ] && declare Text="${*}" || Text="$(cat)" ## could also use read instead of cat ##
[ -z "$Text" ] && printf "$(Bold 'Error:') No text entered...\n\n" >&2 && exit 2

# (4) Process the text
Text="$(echo "$Text" | gsed -rne '1h;1!H;$g;s|[\x0A-\x0D]+| |g;$p' | expand -t4 )"
echo "$Text"    ##  (temporary)   ##
exit 0          ##  (temporary)   ##
...             ## (process text) ##
...             ## (process more) ##
```

Part 3 works for accepting text as entered after options and when piped, but hangs waiting for input if no text is entered and doesn't see text passed as process substitution... eg:

#### Examples:

```sh
./myScript.sh -L10 --width=20 'This is a test'
```

`> This is a test`

```sh
echo 'This is a test' | ./myScript.sh -L10 --width=20
```

`> This is a test`

```sh
./myScript.sh -L10 --width=20 < <( echo 'This is a test' )
```

`> This is a test`

```sh
./myScript.sh -L10 --width=20       ##*** Want to stop this ***##
```

`> (No output)... hangs waiting on cat (or read) for a ^D`

```sh
echo 'This is a test' >( ./myScript.sh )
```

`> This is a test /dev/fd/63`
`> <B>Error:</B> No text entered...`

```sh
./myScript.sh -L10 --width=20 <<<'This is a test'
```

`> This is a test`

```sh
echo "This is a test" | tee >( ./myScript.sh -L10 --width=20 ) >( ./myScript.sh  )
```

`> This is a test`

`> This is a test`

`> This is a test`

How do I get the script to not hang on cat or read, waiting for input? (withoout using timeout or read -t as that just slows things down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want here is to avoid reading from a terminal:

```
if test -t 0; then
    echo "Not reading from terminal.  Pipe through cat if you really want to do this" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

It is not possible to detect the general case where no source of input has been provided specifically to the program; all redirection is done by the shell, and your program cannot tell if its standard input was given specifically to it or inherited from the shell.

Comment: Wow! thanks for the quick response! My first post ever, and I have an answer within 5 minutes of posting!

Comment: Well... got my script working with this simple, but straight to the point answer... so here's a check for you! And I've attached my working script for others who may be interested in how I got it working (I know, I know, slim chance, but there's a _lot_ of people out there... a numbers game), or at least for the other scripter with the same problem.